# How to call class method from javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a form in my application that asks the user for entering some values. This is a web forms app. Those values are product costs that each increase the product value in different manners with complex calculations. Some are percentage others are money, and are depending ones on others or cascaded. some are the readonly calculations result.

All of them, are included in a products POCO class as elements. Even results as calculated.

The form was doing a postback every time the user altered a value, so the POCO elements where updated and the calculated ones where re-bound.
Now I'm getting rid of all postabacks as possible, and replacing those calculations with JS so they are realtime with no server load. Field updates are committed in a row when the user posts the form.

The problem I have is that one of those calculations, depends on calling a method on another POCO class. And I don't know how to resolve it in JS/JQuery.
The example is: The user updates a value on the field "Amount" then we must sum to that value the shipping+duties+adm+... costs that are the result from the POCO method and put it on the result field. Before I had the following inline code:

```
 <%# String.Format("{0:C}", ProductEditing.Amount + DirectCast(DataTable2, ProductExes).CalculateFor(ProductEditing.Amount))%>
```

(The data is stored as datatables, so I must cast to my poco class)
CalculateFor takes the passed value an does some non trivial calculations with the rows he has. Some rows are percentages, some values and some doesn't apply.

Now I'm trying to do something like:

```
var amt = parseFloat($('#<%=txtAmount.ClientID%>').val().replace(',', '.'));
var result = amt + <There call exe calculation passing amount value>;
$('#<%=txtResult.ClientID%>').val(result.toLocaleString());
```

Anyone can please give me a hand? Not so good at Javascript.
I would prefer not to use Pagemethods, if there is some other way that is more independent from the web forms technology.
Don't know if this is clear enough. If it's not, please ask me for a clarification.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without a call to the server. Javascript runs on the client's browser and your POCO objects reside on the server. The best bet would be a call to a webmethod on the page or create a new webservice that accepts the parameters and returns the value.

An alternative is that you can embed the values needed for calculations into javascript variables when your page loads. Then, a javascript function can perform the calculations. I don't know whether this would be feasible for you because those value cannot change once loaded on the page.

Comment: The problem with webmethods is that all elements you access in them must be shared. So for accessing the product exes I must make the datatable, it's Poco... all shared. So webmethods are useless for me. Also I can't embed exes values as they also are present on the same page for editing. It's all for doing prices, amounts adjustments and seeing the results in realtime.

Comment: If all the values are also present on the same page for editing, then is it not possible to pick them up from there? Using jQuery, $('#txtField').val() will get you the value of any field. Maybe I'm missing something else...

Comment: Imagine a product edit page. Product has 10-15 different amount fields that you can edit: discounts, rappel (most) cascaded discounts... In a section you have a grid to enter exes (buying conditions) that apply depending on conditions: duties, taxes, transport. Those exes are stored in a product related table.
When you alter values, exes may be added and results shown on calculated fields.
But I'm getting to the conclusion that you are right, and the editing page is not a place to see that complex calculations. Will leave the question some time in case someone has a solution.